# Merge a list of dataframes within a list in Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, merge

I have 32 separate lists of dataframes.  I need to merge each list together, I am expecting 32 different dataframes.  I know how to merge 1 list of dataframes together, but I am currently doing the calculation 32 different times.  I was wondering if there was a simple way to do the same calculation?  I currently have this and I know I'm creating a new variable but I don't know how to assign it back to the originial list from the input.  "Weather_List" is a list containing every list that contains the dataframes that need to be merged.

sample lists, data and data_day1 contain dataframes that are named "snow", "temp",etc.. weather_list contains the data and data_day1 lists

```
    data = [snow, temp, windspd]
    data_day1 = [snow_day1, temp_day1, windspd_day1]
    weather_list = [data, data_day1]
    def mergedf(item):
        reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['Latitude','Longitude'], how = 'outer'), item


    [mergedf(items) for items in weather_list]
```

I need to use each merged dataframe separate later on in my program.

Answer (score 1):

Consider `map` for elementwise loop through your list of objects which you can upack with `*`.

```py
data = [snow, temp, windspd]
data_day1 = [snow_day1, temp_day1, windspd_day1]
weather_list = [data, data_day1]

def proc_merge(left, right):
    return pd.merge(left, right, on=['Latitude', 'Longitude'])

df_list = list(map(proc_merge, *weather_list))
```

And to retain namings, consider building a dictionary of dataframes with keys and not unnamed list which you  can iterate via a `zip` loop:

```
names = ['snow', 'temp', 'windspd']
df_dict = {nm: lst for nm, lst in zip(names, map(proc_merge, *weather_list))}

df_dict['snow']      # SINGLE DATAFRAME
df_dict['temp']      # SINGLE DATAFRAME
df_dict['windspd']   # SINGLE DATAFRAME
```

For more than two data frames, integrate the `reduce` with open-ended number of arguments:

```py
data = [snow, temp, windspd]
data_day1 = [snow_day1, temp_day1, windspd_day1]
data_day2 = [snow_day2, temp_day2, windspd_day2]
data_day3 = [snow_day3, temp_day3, windspd_day3]

weather_list = [data, data_day1, data_day2, data_day3]

def proc_merge(*dfs):
    return reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on=['Latitude', 'Longitude'], how ='outer'), dfs)

names = ['snow', 'temp', 'windspd']
df_dict = {nm: lst for nm, lst in zip(names, map(proc_merge, *weather_list))}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got a new list of dataframes that are all merged which is what I'm looking.  Is there anyway to do a merge inplace so I can have all the dataframes have the same name as the list?  I need to use those dataframes with those names throughout the rest of my program.

Comment: Hmmm....a Python list is unnamed unlike a dictionary with keys. Can you edit post with sample data to clarify what you mean?

Comment: I have edited the post.  Basically what I am after is data = merge of the 3 dataframes in the list.

Comment: See revamped answer (now that I see actual data objects). Consider using dictionaries instead of lists for name keys. Otherwise, you would need to use the ill-advised `globals()` dictionary to save object names by string references.